# Why does debugging with lldb in VSCode garble chinese characters?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, lldb, vscode-debugger

I dabbled with Rust today and when I tried to print text with chinese characters using `println!` it renders weird characters to the VSCode debug terminal.

I thought the problem would go away after installing language pack, but no such luck. Perhaps additional configuration is needed. It seems a quirk from the VSCode side; I ran `cargo run` from a normal powershell terminal and it works fine.

[image: garbled text]

**main.rs**

```rust
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    println!("Test : {}", "阿拉有一只猫。");

    Ok(())
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug",
            "cargo": {
                "args": [
                    "build",
                    "--bin=test-app",
                    "--package=test-app"
                ],
                "filter": {
                    "name": "test-app",
                    "kind": "bin"
                }
            },
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug unit tests",
            "cargo": {
                "args": [
                    "test",
                    "--no-run",
                    "--bin=test-app",
                    "--package=test-app"
                ],
                "filter": {
                    "name": "test-app",
                    "kind": "bin"
                }
            },
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I was able to reproduce. There's an [issue on the vscode-lldb repository](https://github.com/vadimcn/vscode-lldb/issues/332) with a potential solution, but it feels... *intrusive*... since you have to adjust a Windows global setting. I haven't tried it. The issue seems to be that the terminal created by the lldb extension doesn't think it is UTF-8, though whether this is the fault of vscode or the extension I don't know.

Answer (score 4):

As [@kmdreko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189130/kmdreko) pointed out there is [github issue for that bug](https://github.com/vadimcn/vscode-lldb/issues/332).

I tried the workaround mentioned in the the bug which is enabling the option
`Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support`
in region settings and the problem went away.

Of course this is not the best solution.

If you don't want to rummage the whole control panel for that setting:

- run `control.exe international`
- `Administrative` tab
- `Change system locale` button

[image: region settings]

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the code set setting in the lower right corner is correct. If it is not utf-8 click to modify.

[image: Check to set encoding set to utf-8]

Comment: I'll note that the question is tagged Rust, whose source files [must be utf-8](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/input-format.html); the development tools wouldn't work or at least complain otherwise. However, this answer might be useful for users of other languages that find this post.